# Get the data from scapy command to textfile?

Tags: python, sockets, output, scapy, arp

I am trying to create an ARPscanner based on scapy. I found code from the Internet and I need to modify it to save the results to a `.txt` file. Can anyone help me to do that?

```
lena = int(raw_input("Enter Number : "))
print(lena)

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-5s %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def long2net(arg):
    if (arg <= 0 or arg >= 0xFFFFFFFF):
        raise ValueError("illegal netmask value", hex(arg))
    return 32 - int(round(math.log(0xFFFFFFFF - arg, 2)))

def to_CIDR_notation(bytes_network, bytes_netmask):
    network = scapy.utils.ltoa(bytes_network)
    netmask = long2net(bytes_netmask)
    net = "%s/%s" % (network, netmask)
    if netmask < 16:
        logger.warn("%s is too big. skipping" % net)
        return None

    return net

def scan_and_print_neighbors(net, interface, timeout=1):
    logger.info("arping %s on %s" % (net, interface))
    try:
        ans, unans = scapy.layers.l2.arping(net, iface=interface, timeout=timeout, verbose=True)
        for s, r in ans.res:
            line = r.sprintf("%Ether.src%  %ARP.psrc%")
            try:
                hostname = socket.gethostbyaddr(r.psrc)
                line += " " + hostname[0]
            except socket.herror:
                # failed to resolve
                pass
            logger.info(line)
    except socket.error as e:
        if e.errno == errno.EPERM:     # Operation not permitted
            logger.error("%s. Did you run as root?", e.strerror)
        else:
            raise
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if lena == 1:
        for network, netmask, _, interface, address in scapy.config.conf.route.routes:
            # skip loopback network and default gw
            if network == 0 or interface == 'lo' or address == '127.0.0.1' or address == '0.0.0.0':
                continue

            if netmask <= 0 or netmask == 0xFFFFFFFF:
                continue

            net = to_CIDR_notation(network, netmask)
            if interface != scapy.config.conf.iface:
                # see http://trac.secdev.org/scapy/ticket/537
                logger.warn("skipping %s because scapy currently doesn't support arping on non-primary network interfaces", net)
                #continue
            if net:
                scan_and_print_neighbors(net, interface)
                repr(network)
                text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
                text_file.write(repr(network))

            elif lena == 3 :
                print("Bye Bye  ")
```

I added this code to my script:

```
repr(network)
text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
text_file.write(repr(network))
```

but it does not work, I just got a blank file.

Comment: Any help please

Comment: hellooooooooooooooo any one here to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
sys.stdout = open('textout.txt', 'w')
... rest of your code here ...
sys.stdout.close()
```